# How do you get user inpup and display it in php

Tags: php, input

I am trying to get user input from a text box and then echo it using php. Here is my code, and it is not seeming to work.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo $_POST['value'];
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="value">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh look, an XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['value']))
{
 echo filter_var($_POST['value'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="value">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

First check if form posted.

Comment: Ya i know sanitization , but I just gave why his code is not working.